# javascript - JSTree - why is recursion stopped in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I try to remove a sub-tree ( at least one node ) from a tree, so I build a recursive function :

```
function remove(i)
{
      tree = $('#jstree-tree').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
      j=0;
      console.log(tree);
      while(j<tree.length)
      {
          if(tree[i].id == tree[j].parent)
          {
              remove(j);
              j--;
          }
          j++;
      }

      tree.splice(i,1);
}
```

but the problem here is the Recursion is stopped after the first call, I don't know why [this my code](https://codepen.io/ekka94/pen/MGpQOb).

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need a recursive function. If you want to delete a node, wouldn't you just do `tree.delete_node(obj)`? Or an array of objs to delete more than one.

Comment: `tree` and `j` are global variables now. Are you intentionally doing that?

Comment: i check your code in codepen but i don't see any error?

Comment: thank you  @dpwrussell , but tree.delete_node(obj) is not working and I'm getting an error in my console (tree.delete_node is not a function)

Comment: thank you to @set0gut1 but j is not global variables.

Comment: this is the problem @HoangNK, there is no problem in the code, just after the first call the function is broken and it doesn't continue the iteration in the loop

Comment: @dpwrussell I'm using version 3 of JSTREE

Comment: It's definitely there in the API documentation: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=(&f=delete_node(obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now `j` is a global variable because of declaration without `var`.
Thefore the value of `j` is affected other executions of `remove()`.

Changing `j=0;` to `var j=0;` fix this problem, but it cause infinit loop.
It seems that the recursion of `remove()` is blocking the reflection of `tree` value to `$('#jstree-tree')`.
To avoid this issue, do `tree = ...get_json(...)` at the out side of the recursion and reuse it.

This is working code:

```
function remove(arg)
{
    tree = $('#jstree-tree').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
    var _remove = function (i) {
        var j = 0;
        while(j < tree.length)
        {
            if(tree[i].id == tree[j].parent)
            {
                  _remove(j);
                  j--;
            }
            j++;
        }
        tree.splice(i,1);
    }
    _remove(arg);
}
```